# Issue with Bootstrap row and alignment of multiple Accordion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment, row, accordion

I've recently started looking at BootStrap and I am attempting to create something, which on the surface is very simple although I'm struggling to get my head around it.

I am trying to display three accordion controls next to each other within a single row. I would also like the three accordions to be aligned to the center of the page.

At the moment, all three of my accordion controls begin on their own row with the first accordion positioned in the top left hand corner of the page. I've tried a dozen different things to achieve my goal but I just keep making things worse so I've cleaned up the code as best as I can to present it here.

What is wrong with my code please?

Many thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .container-fluid {
        align-items:center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <!--Start of First Accordian-->
                    <div id="accordion" class="panel-group" style="width:33%">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Placeholder Badge/Icon</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                   <b>IT Department Team Site</b>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Description</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Working Team Site for the IT Dept.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">Owner(s)</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    For access/issues, please contact:<br />
                                    <a href="">Sam</a><br />
                                    <a href="">Chris</a><br />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <!--Start of Second Accordian-->
                    <div id="accordion2" class="panel-group" style="width:33%">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne2">Placeholder Badge/Icon</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseOne2" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <b>IT Department Project Site</b>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo2">Placeholder Badge/Icon</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseTwo2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Project Name Team Site for the IT Dept.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree2">Owner(s)</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseThree2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    For access/issues, please contact:<br />
                                    <a href="">Sam</a><br />
                                    <a href="">Chris</a><br />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <!--Start of Third Accordian-->
                    <div id="accordion3" class="panel-group" style="width:33%">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapseOne3">Placeholder Badge/Icon</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseOne3" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <b>Finance Department Team Site</b>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapseTwo3">Description</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseTwo3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Working Team Site for the Finance Dept.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapseThree3">Owner(s)</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseThree3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    For access/issues, please contact:<br />
                                    <a href="">Sam</a><br />
                                    <a href="">Chris</a><br />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The biggest problem I see is that you're using Bootstrap 4 syntax (flexbox alignments, `.col-sm` without a numeric suffix) but you're including Bootstrap 3...

Comment: you want the three accordions to be aligned vertically or horizontally?

Comment: I would like them aligned horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap uses a grid system with 12 columns. Here you have to replace the `col-sm` with `col-sm-<insert number>`.

The optimal will be to do `col-sm-4` because you have 3 accordion. (3*4 = 12) so you can take the entire page but it's up to you. For more information I invite you to search more about Bootstrap.

Also, you will probably have to retrieve the `style="width:33%"` because it reduce the place that the accordion can take on the page. Test it and see.

Comment: Awesome! I used 'col-sm-4' as you suggested and removed the 33% styling, which has resulted in the three accordions to appear together on a single line.

The three accordions now fit the full page, left to right. If I wanted to reduce the width of each accordion, how would I achieve that? Any suggestion would be most welcomed :-)

Comment: @ArticalDon - By default the accordion will fill the full width of your `.col-*-*` element.  Changing the numerical suffix will change their width, but also result in empty space to the right if your columns fail to add up to 12.

Comment: Many thanks. I've reduced the size to col-sm-3 and I've now got the accordions to the correct size but the row still begins to the left of the page. Ideally I would like to have the center accordion aligned to the center of the page. I'll keep playing.

Comment: @ArticalDon - Seems like you have a very novice understanding of Bootstrap. I'd *really* recommend reading through their documentation.  `.container-fluid` forces the container size to be 100% of your viewport.  If you use just `.container` you get a fixed-width container that will be centered on the screen.

Comment: @RobertC Understood, its now fixed and behaving as it should be. I've only been at this for a few hours but I would like to thank you for your help. It is sincerely appreciated.